# How to install the HTTPRedirectionModule on IIS 7.5 (Windows 7)?

Tags: iis, windows-7, redirect

I'm trying to test redirects on my localhost (Windows 7 running IIS7 ASP.NET 4.6) and after struggling to figure out why it wasn't working I noticed IIS7.5 doesn't come with the **HTTPRedirectioModule** installed. Problem is I can't seem to find a download or instructions on how to install it.

The only instructions I've come across are for Windows Server 2008 and 2012 using Server Manager but I don't have Server Manager installed. I'm confused why such a basic feature isn't installed by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. On the taskbar, click Start, and then click Control Panel.
2. In Control Panel, click Programs and Features, and then click Turn
   Windows Features on or off.
3. Expand Internet Information Services, then World Wide Web Services,
   then Common Http Features.
4. Select HTTP Redirection, and then click OK.

[image]